# Session in PHP not getting registerd

Tags: php

I am trying to develop a simple login page once login `login.php` it should show `index.php`

Below files are in the web directory:

```
> https://www.myowndomain.com/test/status/login.php
> https://www.myowndomain.com/test/status/auth.php
> https://www.myowndomain.com/test/status/index.php
```

So when the user enters index.php it checks if the session is created if so it will show `index.php` if not redirect it to login.php.

If I log in using a valid username and password and click login the PHP file is returning to `login.php`, not to `index.php` (Session is created in `login.php` but when accessing the same on indext.php or auth, session it is blank?

In `index.php` if I don't include `auth.php` - The login works fine but doesn't get the session.

**login.php:**

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username']))
    {

        $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']); // removes backslashes
        $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$username); //escapes special characters in a string
        $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);

    //Checking if user existing in the database or not
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' and password='".md5($password)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo $rows;
        if($rows==1)
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] =  $username;
            echo "User in session:" . $username;

            header("Location: index.php"); // Redirect user to index.php
        }
        else
        {
          echo "<div class='form'><h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="form">
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
<p>Not registered yet? <a href='registration.php'>Register Here</a></p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**auth.php:**

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
$user_check=$_SESSION['username'];

$ses_sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username FROM users where username='$user_check'");

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql);

$login_session=$row['username'];

if(!isset($login_session))
{
    header("Location:login.php");
}
?>
```

What could be wrong here? I have check every bit still issue. Probably someone can recheck my code and tell me the issue? Could it be an issue with the web directory? The files are inside a folder/subfolder/?

Comment: session_start(); should be the fist line of php file. after <?php

Comment: @ObaidulKader: Don't think that is an issue but I have even tried that it doesn't work.

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: Please don’t roll your own authentication (login) system for any reason other than practice, and don’t use your own code for this in production. There are far too many ways to get it wrong and open up major security vulnerabilities. Instead, you should use an existing library or framework that has been thoroughly tested. You already have multiple, significant problems in the code you have posted.

Comment: There's also no reason to use `stripslashes()` or escaping the password before it's hashed. Doing so will _change_ the password for no reason. Specially using something like "stripslashes()" which might _remove_ characters from the password, making it shorter and less secure.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: I have removed the stripslashes, in production I am actually using $mypassword = hash('sha512', $mypassword);

Comment: try after removing the php closing tag(i.e ?>) from the auth.php
As if there is any space then headers already sent and the server will not create session.

Comment: @EdCottrell: It is an internal site being used by only a few users so no issues with writing a simple auth script. :)

Comment: Two things..   using `hash('sha512', ...)` is still less secure than PHP's core function `password_hash()` (since that function generates a secure salt, you can add cost etc). The second thing... why are you showing us code that's different from your production code?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: because I am testing the website from the above location with only three files above. Also, I feel the password issue is secondary as I am trying to fix the session issue.

Comment: If a user isn't logged in, then your `auth.php` should throw a bunch of "undefined index"'s since you're using `$_SESSION['username']` without first checking if it exists. The same goes for `$row['username']`. You're trying to access it without even checking that the query returned anything.

Comment: _"I am testing the website from the above location"_ - That doesn't tell us why you're showing us different code from what you have in production. Specially since you state that the production code is less unsecure.

Comment: @SanjanaNair This is still an extremely bad idea. Your code is insecure, and you cannot assume everyone who accesses it has good intentions. If you need a login page, you need a *secure* login page. Deliberately deploying broken, insecure code is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the obvious security implications of your code, I don't see anything wrong with it. You could try manually setting the session save location. I've found with some hosting that the session path needs to be explicitly set for sessions to work...

`session_save_path("/location/to/save/sessions/");`

To find out what your session save path should be, contact your hosting provider. If you are using localhost - a quick google will do it.